# what is a "mobile_status_update" in the facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

the status_type of "mobile_status_update" is refereed to, but not defined (as far as I can see) in the developer instructions for the facebook graph api [ https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/post ]

Does this just refer to a post that you have made to your own wall?  (feels and odd variable name, but this is what it seems to correspond to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook appear to have used this for backward compatibility. All status updates that don't include images, videos, notes, etc are of the type "mobile_status_update" - The word "mobile" is the confusing part.

There's a recent discussion on this in the developer bug report section of Facebook.com
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/564448573658836/